# Serial line printer - first portion of printed document is corrupted

Tags: bash, tty, cups, lpr

I am trying to print a document with a serial printer using the command `lpr`.

The model of printer that I have is Craden DP-9. I am finding [the technical manual](http://www.craden.com/Site/images/Tk10tot.pdf) to be difficult to understand,  because it assumes a certain level of familiarity with archaic line printing technology.

## Setup

The printer is installed/registered in CUPs as `printer1`. I can talk to the printer over a USB to serial adapter from my laptop. It reliably exhibits a response to printing jobs, but the documents that come out are always scrambled in various ways.

I am reasonably certain that the printer is in good condition because the self-test document comes out perfectly.

## Code

Here is the code that I am attempting to print things with.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Created on 2023-09-10T17:52:18-04:00
# Author: nate

set -eo pipefail

if [[ -z "$1" || ! -f "$1" ]] ; then
    echo "Please provide an input file."
    exit 0
fi

tempfile="$(mktemp)"
trap "rm -f $tempfile" EXIT

WIDTH="90"
LINES="60"
MARGIN="0"

cat "$1" \
    | unix2dos\
    | tee "$tempfile"\
    | lpr -P printer1 -o raw

cat "$tempfile"
```

When I run this bash script to print the source code of the script itself:

```
./print.sh ./print.sh
```

Here is a scan of the resulting document:

[image: Here is a scan of the resulting document.]

A scan of the self-test document, containing debug information:

[image: A scan of the self-test document, containing debug information.]

## My question

- Why is the beginning of the document scrambled?
- For those more familiar with these types of line printers than I am, what are the typical avenues for debugging this type of line printer problem?

Any help is appreciated!

## Edit: output of lpoptions

```
copies=1 device-uri=serial:/dev/ttyUSB0?baud=38400+bits=8+parity=none+flow=soft finishings=3 job-cancel-after=10800 job-hold-until=no-hold job-priority=50 job-sheets=none,none marker-change-time=0 number-up=1 print-color-mode=monochrome printer-commands=AutoConfigure,Clean,PrintSelfTestPage printer-info printer-is-accepting-jobs=true printer-is-shared=true printer-is-temporary=false printer-location printer-make-and-model='IBM ProPrinterII Foomatic/ibmpro (recommended)' printer-state=3 printer-state-change-time=1694275126 printer-state-reasons=none printer-type=8564740 printer-uri-supported=ipp://localhost/printers/printer1
```

Comment: I don't see why you post here the script. This should be irrelevant: If you just print the document using `lpr` from the command line, the printout looks the same, doesn't it?

Comment: @user1934428 actually it is not the same, because the script invokes unix2dos. Anyway, we should know the configuration of lpr. For example, the conversion of unix single LF to CR-LF should be a duty of lpr (or cups).

Comment: You can do all the actions of the scripts manually, and safe the result into a file. Then you print the file from the command line. If the output then looks bad, it is not a programming problem, but a problem on how you have configured your printer. In this case, the question is off-topic here, but could be asked at [su].

Comment: I posted this trivial script because it was necessary to have some document to show what the input/output of the print job looks like

Comment: Added the output of lpoptions, please let me know any other information that would be useful

Comment: I see a potential problem. CUPS seems programmed with "flow=soft" while the printer seems to use "protocol=DTR" (DTR is a pin of the serial port, "data terminal ready"). You should investigate and try to make that two options/protocols match.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried changing from flow=soft to protocol=DTR via the CUPS admin panel, and the printer was not responsive.